# Homology group of the product of spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am trying to complete an exercise where I am told to compute the homology group of $S^n \times S^m$.

Previously they have told me to decompose $S^{n+m+1}$ as the union of $S^n \times D^{m+1}$ and $D^{n+1}\times S^m$ along their common boundary $S^n\times S^m$, so I suppose I will need to use that fact. However, I do not know how to use it.

Can anyone give me a clue, please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a Mayer-Vietoris hint.

Comment: Kunneth.......!

Comment: Also, what kind of coefficients are you using?

Comment: I am working with $\mathbb{Z}$. I tried to use Mayer-Vietoris but since $S^n\times D^{m+1}$ and $D^{n+1}\times S^m$ are not open in the union, I don't know how to define the open sets. Moreover, I haven't studied Kunneth Theorem yet.

Comment: You can fatten them up a little bit to make them open and not disturb too much.  For this you may need the homotopy axiom.